# Android Studio BSOD when running virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, haxm, bsod

When I attempt to start a virtual device the laptop crashes and I get a BSOD with the error: IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. 
I opened up the crash log and I found the culprit to be:

```
MODULE_NAME: IntelHaxm

IMAGE_NAME:  IntelHaxm.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5cb6c325

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  28a8

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_CODE_AV_IntelHaxm!unknown_function

BUCKET_ID:  AV_CODE_AV_IntelHaxm!unknown_function

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  AV_CODE_AV_IntelHaxm!unknown_function
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm hitting this, too.  New install of AS (Pixel, Intel Atom, latest "10" image), went to BIOS to enable VT-x, back to AS, Run, BSOD.  Every time AS tries to launch the virtual device: BSOD.  Go to BIOS and disable VT-x.  Now no crash.  Won't launch device either, of course.

Comment: `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` means that a driver had broken away.

Comment: @brianWhite I'm suffering with this same issue, trying to run Emulator in Android studio for Flutter! (everything was working fine before)

Answer (score 15):

This happens when the IntelHaxm driver isn't properly installed.  If VT-x is not enabled in the BIOS when Android Studio installs, Haxm will not setup properly.

If you then enable VT-x but not reinstall the driver, Android Studio will try to use the unconfigured driver and you'll get this crash.

To reinstall Haxm, go under `Tools > SDK Manager` and install it manually.  ([image ref](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/android-studio/haxm-installation-failed-install-intel-haxm-in-windows/))

[image]

There was also a version of the driver that had a bug that caused this.  Make sure you `Help > Check for Updates...` so you have the latest edition.  Be sure VT-x is enabled in the BIOS first.

Comment: I went to SDK tools and needed to update intel x86 emulator and the emulator stopped crashing. Thanks (y)

Comment: You saved my day !! It resoled my crash. Thanks

Comment: My BSOD error was PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA, but the solution worked for it, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have "Intell x 86 Emulator" to be sure that you use the actual version. Try to update it. if you use not the latest version there would be an updating available.

[image]